# Import csv from git into Scala 3

Tags: scala, github, import-from-excel

I am a spark scala newbie and I am trying to import a csv file from git repo into scala 3. I have tried using the panda example but, I am getting a few errors.

Errors:

```
Cannot resolve symbol url_github
; or new line expected (this is on the fd_df = fd.read_csv(url_github)
Cannot resolve symbol fd_df
Cannot resolve symbol read_csv
Cannot resolve symbol spark
Cannot resolve symbol spark_df
```

This is the code that I tried and I was expecting to see the file written to the console in scala, but, I got 9 errors instead.

```scala
import _root_.{flightData => fd}

url_github = Symbol("https")://github.com/abcde/Work/blob/main/flightData.csv'

fd_df = fd.read_csv(url_github)
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(fd_df)

spark_df.limit(100000).show()
```

Comment: import _root_.{flightData => fd}

object ReadCSVOne extends App {
  url_github = Symbol("https"): //github.com/abcde/Work/blob/main/flightData.csv'

    fd_df;fd.read_csv()
  spark_df = spark.createDataFrame()

  spark_df.limit().show()

  case class fd_df()
}

Comment: I updated my code.  When I run it, I get this error now.                                  
 object flightData is not a member of package <root>
import _root_.{flightData => fd}

Comment: This isn't a valid Scala code, haven't you mixed up some Jupyter examples for Scala and Python with some definitions missing?

Comment: probably so @MateuszKubuszok